# ~/.inputrc causes CTRL+arrows not to work

Tags: bash, inputrc

When `~/.inputrc` does **not** exist, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> on a Bash command line moves the cursor back and forward by one word, respectively.

However, if `~/.inputrc` exists (regardless of whether or not it's empty), those two key combos result in `;5D` and `;5C` being printed where the cursor is instead of moving the cursor.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its because if the file exists, bash uses your local settings for the readline settings instead of the default one.

From http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html

> "When a program which uses the Readline library starts up, the init file is read, and the key bindings are set."

The recommendation in the sample file at gnu.org is to source the default in your local one with a line like this:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
```

and then modify from there.

Comment: Still valid, at least on this somewhat old production server with old bash that I'm dealing with. I created a ~/.inputrc, and added "$include /etc/inputrc" ( without the quote ) to it. For some reason it won't get parsed when I ssh to the machine, but it does if I open a new bash shell by command. Creating .inputrc solved that though.

Answer (score 0):

`set -o emacs` in your `~/.profile` should do it.

Comment: I put `set -o emacs` in `~/.profile` and ran `touch ~/.inputrc` . Unfortunately, the CTRL+LARROW and CTRL+RARROW keys still caused `;5D` and `;5C` to be printed instead of moving the cursor.